# block, following after 'let' is not finished. Statement required

Tags: f#

First of all I want to point out that I could translate the error message in uncorrect way... What is this error about? How should I write my code?

```
    [EntryPoint]
    let Main (args:string[]) =
            let start = startServer (args.[0]) 
            Console.Read()
```

I do not understand what should I do to let compiler be happy. Is the following code snippet correct?

```
let rec handle =
       let handler = socket.Accept()   
       let rec recieveData =
           let bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes)
           let data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec)
           Console.WriteLine( "Text received : {0}", data)
       Console.Read()
   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what your code is supposed to do because it has outside dependencies, but at a minimum your problem is indentation: whitespace in F# is significant and in particular plays a significant role in determining lexical scope. So for starters you need to fix indentation, something like

```
[EntryPoint]
let Main (args:string[]) =
    let start = startServer (args.[0]) 
    Console.Read()

let rec handle =
   let handler = socket.Accept()   
   let rec recieveData =
       let bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes)
       let data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec)
       Console.WriteLine( "Text received : {0}", data)
   Console.Read()
   0
```

Also, your employment of `rec` values appears unnecessary if not incorrect. And it's odd that you perform a bunch of work in the body of the `handle` let expression only to bind it to `0`... do you mean `handle` or `recieveData` to be functions? If so maybe you intended something more like

```
let handle socket = //make handle a function with socket an explicit dependency
   let handler = socket.Accept()
   let bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes)
   let data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRec)
   Console.WriteLine( "Text received : {0}", data)
   Console.Read() |> ignore //probably you are using Read to wait for user interaction to continue, but just ignore the result (returning unit) instead of returning 0
```

Comment: I am just starting server using sockets. Thanks for your enhancement:)

Answer (score 1):

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let Main (args : string[]) =
    let start = startServer args.[0]
    Console.Read()
```